# Dynamic addition/deletion of domain TLS certificates using cert-manager/Traefik

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, traefik-ingress, cert-manager

I'm interested in an automated solution for managing cluster TLS certificates for domains, which would allow for adding and removing `Certificate`s (controlled by cert-manager) as well as `IngressRoute`s (controlled by Traefik).

So the task is essentially as follows: when a new **domain name** is added to the database, some automated process should pick it up, add a new `Certificate` and a new `IngressRoute` object for it. And vice versa, as soon as a name is deleted, it should clean up the certificate and the route.

From that point on, the rest will be taken care of automatically (I mean, the certificate issuance).

Is it something than can be achieved by the means of some standardized tool or API? Or should I go for a hardcore programmatic implementation that would call Kubernetes API directly?

Comment: I wonder if [ingress-shim](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/release-0.7/tasks/issuing-certificates/ingress-shim.html#:~:text=ingress%2Dshim%20watches%20Ingress%20resources,described%20on%20the%20Ingress%20exists.) could be what you need ?

Comment: @matt_j looks interesting. Does it support Traefik's IngressRoutes (couldn't derive that from the docs)?  Apart from that, there's still that bit that the ingresses have to be created based on the database content, so it can only solve half of my problem

Comment: @yktoo I am now facing the same problem, what is the solution that you did eventually?

Comment: @DiaaEddin I ended up writing my own implementation that performs synchronisation between the database and the cluster, talking to Kubernetes API directly. My implementation is in Go, but I guess you can use other languages, too.

Comment: @yktoo how many domains do you have? for example Is it scalable for thousends of domains?

Comment: @DiaaEddin it's a trivial list comparison, so I guess your performance will be limited by your database and k8s performance. I don't see why it wouldn't scale to thousands of domains, but that needs to be proven in practice of course.